# is it possible to refer to anonymous array in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
for (var name in ['dog','cat','cow']) {
  alert(name);
}
```

The `name` here is returning the index of the array, but I can't refer to it since it's anonymous.

I know I can declare it outside the loop, but here I'm asking if is there a way for refering to the name directly that is without index.

Comment: If you could refer to the array, then it wouldn't be anonymous anymore...

Comment: Some scripting languages provide a magical variable (perl has $_) that gives access to otherwise anonymous members; I think that's what rsk82 may have been thinking of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the keys of the array are going to be integers, there's nothing that necessitates the use the `for..in` construct.

```
for (var arr = ['dog','cat','cow'], name = 0; name < arr.length; name++ ) {
  console.log(arr[ name ]);
}
```

In the above code, a simpler `for` loop allows for the creation of a new object and referencing by key inside the loop.

Comment: `arr++`, really? Also, using `name` for array index - **bad** choice, IMHO.

Comment: The arr mistake was fixed before you posted. The name var was based on his existing code. The var name `name` is *not* a reserved keyword though it's used in some non-standard implementations (Function.name). You should down the competitiveness. It's better to be helpful than fast or elegant.

Comment: I meant, when I see a `name`, I expect it to be a string, not an integer.

Comment: As this answer got accepted, NB that the `arr` variable will be visible everywhere outside the loop. Also, it's better to cache the array length, it must not be changed during the incrementing loop.

Comment: @katspaugh good point. Another reason to cache the array length is that it is calculated for every iteration.  `for(var arr=[], name=0, len = arr.length; name<len; name++) { }`

Answer (score 14):

...no. There isn't, not a native loop at least. There is, however, ES5's [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
['dog', 'cat', 'cow'].forEach(function(value, key) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Which is practically the same. It's supported [mostly everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5), except in old IE: something like [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for example enables ES5 methods even in such old browsers, though.

Comment: As of 2015, Firefox, Chrome and Webkit browsers supports this method. I don't know about IE as I have no Windows to test on.

Comment: IE supports it from IE9 onwards, so that's basically all the versions most people would want to support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5

Answer (score 5):

You have several options.

If you are using jQuery you can do this:

```
$.each(['dog','cat','cow'], function() {
    var name = this;
    alert(this);
});
```

If you are not using jQuery you can create your own function

```
function each(array, pFunction) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        pFunction(element);
    }
}

each(['dog','cat','cow'], function(name) {
    alert(name);
});
```

If you don't want to create a function you can always do something crazy like this: (don't recommend it)

```
for (var name in { 'dog' : '','cat' : null,'cow' : null }) {
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that last option is no longer an array but a JSON-formatted hash where you're iterating the keys. Clever, if not necessarily obvious at first glance (as you've said, not recommended ;^D).

Answer (score 3):

If the array is anonymous you cannot refer to its elements using a `for in` loop.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do it. It will show only the indexes. Besides, **for in loop for array in JavaScript is a bad practice. It will loop through all the array objects method.**

Answer (score 2):

Array methods `forEach`, `map`, `filter` and so on will iterate through a literal array's indexes:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'cow'].forEach(alert);
```

Shim for older browsers:

```
if(![].forEach){
    array.prototype.forEach= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, L= T.length, i= 0;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in T){
                    fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong syntax construction for this.

`for in` is for enumerating object's properties, not for iterating arrays. Declare your array outside and use regular loop.

```
var arr = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow'];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // your code
}
```